# How to check if object exist in MinIO bucket using MinIO Java SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, sdk, minio

I currently working on a Spring web app with MinIO object storage. And i need to implement a function that check if upload file is successfully upload or not or check if the file exist in the bucket.

And from my research every information I found are outdated and cannot be use with latest MinIO Java SDK. That why I decide to ask this question here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After digging through MinIO Java SDK for a while. I found that if you call statObject function in the minioClient, it will only be successful when object exist in the bucket. And throw an ErrorResponseException when object doesn't exist.

So I came up with this function.

```
public boolean isObjectExist(String name) {
        try {
            minioClient.statObject(StatObjectArgs.builder()
                    .bucket(defaultBucketName)
                    .object(name).build());
            return true;
        } catch (ErrorResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript and Node js I have did the following

```
exports.isObjectExistInMinio = async(bucketName, fileName)=> {
    try {
        await Minio.minioClient.statObject(bucketName, fileName);
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the call fails because the server is down?